# Unsupported hash type error with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, hashlib

I am running a genome sequence alignement software tool (Stampy) that requires Python 2.7, which I installed several months ago on our Ubuntu 20.04 server.

When running the software tool, I persistently get the following error:

```
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jeremy/sweden/pipeline_run/run_H8_Blockbi/python/lib/python2.7   /hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
```

which seem to indicate problems with Python 2.7 libraries. However, it's not clear to me what I need to install to correct this problem (I tried reinstalling Python 2.7 and the problem remains, in spite of the fact that hashlib is a standard library for Python2.7 and later versions, and hashlib itself seems to be there and import successfully).

Any suggestions on how to correct this (I found a StackOverflow thread about a similar problem where the solutions were unfortunately geared specifically to MacOS systems)

Comment: Hash type sha224 should [always be available](https://pymotw.com/3/hashlib/index.html). There are a number of "dot" releases of 2.7 — up to v2.7.18 I think. Make sure you have the latest one installed.

Comment: I have 2.7.18 installed (in fact, I reinstalled it a few days ago just in case the problem was due to an incomplete installation or some similar glitch). There's a whole set of sha hash types that give the same error, sha512 etc.

Comment: The docs say what's available depends on the "OpenSSL library that Python uses on your platform", so maybe that's messed-up.

Comment: What would I need to do to correct this?

Comment: I have no idea how to fix it. It sounds like it might be a part of your platform.

Comment: Would it be advisable to try reinstalling the OpenSSL library, or is this likely to just generate additional incompatibility issues?

Comment: I wouldn't advise try it unless you have some way of undoing it — like a system back-up.